# Matt black vinyl fabric for upholstery, cleaning/sealing?

Tags: cleaning, upholstery

I have been doing some upholstery using a cloth-backed vinyl with a matt-black finish. It looks great... until the oils from your hands or hair touch it.

Is there a way to clean this type of fabric and/or seal it so that it doesn't mark so easily?

I was told to simply clean with warm soapy water and micro fibre cloth but it just leaves a bigger mark where it was cleaned.